# Is there some way to deal with good answers to poor questions

Tags: discussion

Suppose I asked a bad question likely to be closed as duplicate or offtopic etc. but among the answers were one that I found substantially valuable that while didn't exactly answer my question (because the question was poorly asked in the first place), provided some good information that I believe would be useful for other users.

Should I ask another (hopefully better) question and leave a comment asking the original author to repost his answer on my new question for me to accept?  Or do I ask and answer my own question, copy and pasting what he said?  Is there someway to "migrate" an answer to another question?

Comment: Why can't you just leave everything as it is, upvote the answer, and let them earn a Reversal badge? Why are you compelled to move the contents of the answer elsewhere?

Comment: Also, I didn't notice this the first time, but a question being closed as a duplicate *does not* imply that it is a "bad" question. Often, duplicates can be difficult to find if you are not already familiar with the topic. I'll frequently close questions as duplicates of something that I would never have reasonably expected the original asker to have found. (Of course, by the same token, there are lots of duplicates that provide clear evidence that the person who asked them didn't even bother to try searching. This doesn't make them "bad" questions, either; just lazy ones!)

Answer (score 2):

If the question can be closed as a duplicate, the answer could be re-posted (By the answerer) on the duplicate target, provided it *adds* to that question.
So, if the answer provides some kind of new insight, the dupe target is *the* place to share it.

If the question can be closed as off-topic, the answer is unlikely to be on-topic on Stack Overflow. In that case, it's probably better off not being reposted anywhere.

In the end, [duplicates shouldn't be answered](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) in the first place. The same goes for off-topic questions.